# mysql data substraction from column of one table to column of another table

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have two different table named `1. users 2. transaction` And both table have 'amount' name column.

I need to subtract `users-> amount` column from `transaction-> amount` column and then store that subtracted value to `users-> amount` column.

Table structure:

```
users have column: id(primary key),username,amount
transaction have column: id (primary key),username,transaction_id,amount
```

Here i want `users.amount = users.amount - transaction.amount` where `id` of both table are same.

Comment: Please post table structure, including column names and also how your two tables can be joined.

Comment: i have edited question.please check it @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following update query:

```
UPDATE users t1
INNER JOIN transaction t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.amount = t1.amount - t2.amount
```

This assumes that, as you said, the `id` columns from both tables identifies a user.  It also assumes that you want to update every record in the `users` table without restriction.  If not, then you can easily add a `WHERE` clause to the update query.